# How to check if all leaves are positioned to the left side of the BinaryTree

Tags: binary-tree

i've been breaking my head on an tasks my lecturer posted as prep for the exams. The problem would be relative easy to solve if it weren't for his "own" take on the definition of a Perfect Binary Tree.

My Task is this: "Check if any given BinaryTree is complete (complete = all but the last level needs to be full  ***AND*** on the last level all leaves need to be at the left side of the tree. Write a ***pointer*** implementation. So below tree is a Complete/Perfect tree in his definition.

```
       A

   B       C
D     E  F
```

Nearly all info on the internet on Perfect or Full trees don't tackle the specific requirement of " All leaves need to be on the left side".

What i've done so far is write a class that get the total number of nodes in a given tree and compare it to the expected number based on the Perfect tree formula ( Math.pow(2, depth)-1))

Here is my code:

```
private int numberOfNodes =0;


public void printLevelorder(){
    LinkedBlockingQueue<BinaryNode<E>> stack = new LinkedBlockingQueue<BinaryNode<E>>();
    BinaryNode<E> node = root;
    stack.offer(node);
    while( !stack.isEmpty()){
        node = stack.poll();
        if( node != null){
            if( node.getLeft() != null){
                stack.offer(node.getLeft());
            }if( node.getRight() != null){
                stack.offer(node.getRight());
            }
            numberOfNodes++;
            System.out.print(node.toString()+ " ");
        }

        else{

            return;
        }


    }
    System.out.println();
}
public int getMaxDepth(BinaryNode<E> node){
    int l =0, r =0;
    if( node != null){
        if( node.getLeft() != null){
            l = getMaxDepth(node.getLeft());
        }if( node.getRight() != null){
            r = getMaxDepth(node.getRight());
        }
    }
    return 1 + Math.max(l,r);
}

public boolean isComplete(){
    return isComplete(root);

}

private boolean isComplete(BinaryNode<E> node){

    int depth = this.getMaxDepth(node);
 int expectedNodes = (int)(Math.pow(2,depth)-1);
 System.out.println( numberOfNodes + "  -  " + expectedNodes);


return false;
}
```

Comment: Could you create a fiddle with the code you have? http://jsfiddle.net/ And also wahat language do you need to make it in? jquery, javascript, php ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding so quickly ! I need to write it in Java.  Jsfiddle.net allows java code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i understand from your question is that you simply have to [check for a complete binary tree](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-given-binary-tree-is-complete-tree-or-not/) by doing a level order traversal starting from root.

During the traversal, once you find a node which is NOT a Full Node (A node is *Full Node* if both left and right children are not empty), all the following nodes must be leaf nodes.

**If a node has empty left child, then the right child must be empty.**

Comment: Exactly, looking over the link you send. Based on the tree results this is exactly what i need. Thanks !

Comment: Glad could help. If you found the answer useful, you could mark it as your accepted answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on the very helpful link send by @poorvank_bhatia my solution in java is this:

```
public void printPostorder(BinaryNode node){
    if( node == null) return;
    printPostorder(node.getLeft());
    printPostorder(node.getRight());
    System.out.print(node.toString()+ " ");
    numberOfNodes++;        
}

public int getNumberOfNodes(){
    return numberOfNodes;           
}

public boolean isComplete(){
    return isComplete(root,0);

}

public boolean isComplete(BinaryNode node, int index){
    if( node == null) return true;

    if( index >= numberOfNodes) return false;

    return (isComplete(node.getLeft(), 2*index +1) 
            && isComplete(node.getRight(),2*index +2));

}
```